# How do programmers usually interface with stock data?

Tags: algorithmic-trading

When a programmer talks about using something like the S&P 500 index to create trading algorithms, from what source does this data update in a format a computer can scan?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API for stock price?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058323/api-for-stock-price)

Answer (score 0):

### Prolog:

**a)** Trading strategy is typically not proposed by programmers.
**b)** Programmers are typically responsible for implementing a trading strategy ( code it )
**c)** Trading strategy gets to the programming phase if & only if there is a quantitatively tested reasonably robust edge ( <sub>Obviously it makes no sense to implement any underperforming model, does it?</sub> )
**d)** Given the **c)**, the Quants are well equipped with adequate technical + fundamental data, to execute quantitative modelling prior to driving a decision, whether **b)** would ever start or not.
**e)** APIs / DataStores for in-vitro Quant modelling are by far different from APIs / Streaming Gateways used for feeding a real-time operation of the same Trading Strategy in-vivo.

---

### Epilogue:

> If just seeking for an API to play with,
> one has better [start with a few details about **Legal Aspects**](http://meumobi.github.io/stocks%20apis/2016/03/13/get-realtime-stock-quotes-yahoo-finance-api.html),
> **next**,
> if feasible,
> one may enjoy a **[collection of about a hundred API](https://www.programmableweb.com/news/96-stocks-apis-bloomberg-nasdaq-and-etrade/2013/05/22)**-s, historically opened for this or similar purpose ( some of 'em did not end up as just a dust covered memento in the fast flow of time ).